# jQuery and CSS: Sidebar should push out above flexbox content, without influencing the main area

Tags: jquery, css

I need a website with a special navigation. So far, I worked with HTML, CSS, and jQuery. This is my code:

```js
$(".left_button").click(function() {
  $(".left").toggleClass("left_after");
});

$(".right_button").click(function() {
  $(".right").toggleClass("right_after");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  cursor: default;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

.content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  margin-left: -150px;
}

.left_after {
  margin-left: 0;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.right {
  margin-right: -150px;
}

.right_after {
  margin-right: 0;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.sidebar_content {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left_button,
.right_button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="sidebar left">
    <div class="sidebar_content">Here is some toggle content.</div>
    <div class="left_button">Toggle</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    This is the main area. This is the main area. This is the main area. This is the main area. This is the main area. This is the main area. This is the main area. This is the main area.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar right">
    <div class="right_button">Toggle</div>
    <div class="sidebar_content">Here is some toggle content.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you click one of the two toggle buttons, the width of the main area must not change. Everything else looks exactly how it should look like.

Would be very thankful for help. Have a good night, morning, or day. ;)

And a further question: If you click to display the toggle content, and click in the main area, the toggle content should disappear. How is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `transition` , `transform` with `translateX` instead of operating over `margin` or `left` / `right` properties.
- Use just a single `.is-active` class, that way you can `.removeClass`-it from both elements in a simple fashion

```js
const $left = $(".left"); // Cache selectors to Elements you use multiple times
const $right = $(".right"); 

$(".left_button").on("click", function() {
  $left.toggleClass("is-active");
});

$(".right_button").on("click", function() {
  $right.toggleClass("is-active");
});

$(".main").on("click", function() {
  $left.add($right).removeClass("is-active");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* you forgot this one */
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  color: white;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

.content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s; /* cool stuff ahead */ 
}

.left  { margin-left: -150px; }
.right { margin-right: -150px; }
.left.is-active  { transform: translateX(150px); }
.right.is-active { transform: translateX(-150px); }

.main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.sidebar_content {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left_button,
.right_button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="sidebar left">
    <div class="sidebar_content">Here is some toggle content.</div>
    <div class="left_button">Toggle</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    This is the main area. This is the main area. This is the main area. This is the main area. This is the main area. This is the main area. This is the main area. This is the main area.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar right">
    <div class="right_button">Toggle</div>
    <div class="sidebar_content">Here is some toggle content.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```